# AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'id' Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I am trying to fill dropdown form using Selenium. I am trying select the dropdown element by its ID but getting this error: **AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'id'** I am getting this error for this line: `element = driver.find_element(By.id('State'))`

```
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from sre_parse import State
from tkinter.tix import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
# web = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://ssg2021.in/citizenfeedback")

time.sleep(2)

element = driver.find_element(By.id('State'))
drp = Select(element)

drp.select_by_visible_text('Chhattisgarh')
```

Comment: driver.find_element(By.ID,'State') it's not Java.

Comment: what is the same code for python ?

Comment: Just wrote it in the comment.

Comment: I also recommend using webdriver waits.

Comment: No luck. Still getting the same error.

Comment: There I added an example for it.

Comment: Thanks. I solved that attribute error too. It was my typo.

Comment: No problem accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: @vatsalay: for typo questions, we've this Guiding principal, `Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,30)                                 
driver.get("https://ssg2021.in/citizenfeedback")
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"State")))
drp = Select(element)
drp.select_by_visible_text('Chhattisgarh')
```

Just wait for presence of element and then select by text.

Outputs:

[image]

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try as following

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('State'))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('Chhattisgarh')
```